# In PHP, How to convert unicode number strings into numbers correctly?

Tags: php, string, csv, unicode, ansi

I have csv file encoded in unicode and when I read it either with fgetcsv or fgets and try to use the number strings as integer numbers in PHP, only the first character of the string is casting into a number, i.e

```
$str='2012';
$num=$str + 0; OR $num=(int)$str;
echo $num;
results -> 2
```

How can I convert these unicode number strings correctly?

I was not successful using conversion functions in PHP from unicode to other charsets!

The only way I know is to use a simple text editor like notepad or notepad++ and convert the file format to an ANSI csv.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: "Unicode" is not an encoding. What Microsoft calls "Unicode" is actually UTF-16LE.

Comment: What flavour of Unicode are you using? In UTF-8 this should just work. Either way, convert to ASCII and it will definitely work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

convert it to some other encoding, like UTF-8.

```
$str = mb_convert_encoding( $str, "UTF-8", "UTF-16LE");
```

Your string is actually like this (Manually constructed UTF-16LE):

```
 $str = "2\x000\x001\x002\x00";
```

So php reads the first `2` and then sees `NUL` which is not a number, and you get `2`.

BTW, LE BOM isn't handled here (`\xFF\xFE`) so show your full code and I will see.

Comment: Thanks Esailija,
I could read all the file contents into one string and convert it from UTF-16LE to UTF-8, then write it back.
Then using fgets to read one line of csv file at a time, except that there remains an extra character at the beginning of the first line which I remove it using substr only for the first line. Thanks again.

Comment: @Mehrdad if you are going to do that, use `UTF-16` if the file has BOM. `UTF-16LE` doesn't eat the BOM unfortunately, so it will be in the resulting file at the start

Comment: I'm using this code and it works properly:

$filestr = file_get_contents($path);
$filestr = mb_convert_encoding($filestr, 'ASCII', 'UTF-16LE');
file_put_contents($path, substr($filestr, 1));